# Laravel DB::Raw with Average

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a laravel application which has the a model for orders.

The model contains:

```
id
order_date
value
```

I'm looking to return the average total daily sales value across a period.

For example, see below sample dataset

```
1 | 2017-11-01 | 10.00
2 | 2017-11-01 | 10.00
3 | 2017-11-01 | 11.00
4 | 2017-11-02 | 14.00
5 | 2017-11-03 | 1.00
6 | 2017-11-03 | 18.00
7 | 2017-11-03 | 10.00
8 | 2017-11-03 | 10.00
9 | 2017-11-04 | 105.00
10 | 2017-11-04 | 10.00
```

I'm looking to return the total value of each day but then average across the days.

```
1/11/2017 = 31
2/11/2017 = 14
3/11/2017 = 39
4/11/2017 = 115
```

resulting in the answer for the above: 49.75

I've tried the following eloquent query but failed to get the right value, it's almost like the group by is being ignored and its averaging the order value rather than the total order value for the day, can some one point me in the right direction?

```
$avg = Order::whereBetween('order_date',array(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()))->groupBy('order_date')->avg('value');
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed, your current query will average the value per date, instead of by the number of days. You'll have to tweak the query to use some division:

```
$avgValue = Order::whereBetween('order_date',array(Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(), Carbon::now()->endOfMonth()))
->selectRaw('SUM(value) / COUNT(DISTINCT order_date) AS order_average')
->first();
```

You should the be able to get the value with `$avgValue->order_average`