# How to get Average of Tasks completed on Specific Date

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have Task model it contain task_status column and due_date column. I want to get average of each date between date array.

```
Task::whereIn('due_date', $dates)
            ->where('task_status',$status)
            ->where('user_id', \Auth::id())
            ->whereRAW('YEAR(due_date) =?', Carbon::now()->format('Y'))
            ->groupBy('due_date')
            ->orderBy('due_date', 'DESC')
            ->get(array(
                DB::raw('Date(due_date) as date'),
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "count"')
            ));
```

status is complete or incomplete

Comment: Try the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021947/how-can-i-make-an-average-of-dates-in-mysql

Comment: i am not able to find solutions but thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel DB::Raw with Average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47270407/laravel-dbraw-with-average)

Comment: i have different task with status complete and incomplete and i want to display average of completed task for everyday , monthwise and weekly.